# Vinyl to concrete bonding

Tags: adhesive

I ordered a set of panels from waterproofing.com for their "SealOnce" system to sorta block off the basement drains from the cats / prevent some debris from getting in from their boxes.

http://waterproof.com/sealonce-diy-basement-waterproofing-system/

I didn't order their adhesive/mastic - what big box store product would be appropriate to use for mating the vinyl to concrete?

From the images on their site it looks more like a caulk to me the way they spread it?

Comment: It looks like their sealant is one of the big selling points, and at $8/tube I'm not aware of an alternative that would be high quality and much less expensive.  That's the going rate for high-end silicone type adhesives.

Comment: @JPhi1618 wasn't sure if it was just an inflated price with a wrapper or not.

Comment: The price is on the high end, but not unreasonable.  If you look at [outdoor sealants](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Paint-Paint-Tools-Supplies-Caulk-Sealants/Outdoor/N-5yc1vZc5bpZ1z11epf), many of them are in the $6-7 range with some polyurethane and silicone sealants over $8.  Many of those sealants will work, but I'm not sure which I would point to as "the best".

Comment: Gotcha, looks like Liquid Nails Fuze It, but maybe too runny. I might just bite the bullet and buy from them. They are using an electric gun though, so I wonder how hard it'll be to use with the manual caulk gun.

Comment: Pro's use electric guns because they are working quickly all day and your hand gets tired.  It's not because it's too hard to squeeze out, it's just that doing it all day is hard.  And yea, in situations like this, I would pay a little more to know that I had "the right" stuff.  Unless it's a big job or costs are super important - then you will just have to try a few cheaper options to see what seems to work.  Of course you have no way to test longevity.